# How to add border with text on image in c#?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, digital-signature

I am creating image from string image. I want to add left and bottom border and also want to add text with border. So I have make r&d over google but not getting proper solution for that.
I am getting image like below :

[image]

However I need image like below (left side half border, bottom half border and then unique id after bottom half border) :

[image]

So how to achive it. I am working in c# and my code is like as below :

```
string fullName = name.Trim();
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
string fontName = _fontfamily + ".ttf";
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/fontCss/" + fontName));
FontFamily ff = privateFontCollection.Families[0];
Font font = new Font(ff, 25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
int width = (int)graphics.MeasureString(fullName, font).Width;
int height = (int)graphics.MeasureString(fullName, font).Height;
bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent);
bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(width, height));
graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
graphics.DrawString(fullName, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";

var newImage = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height + 50);
var gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
gr.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);
gr.DrawString("uniqueId", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, bitmap.Height, bitmap.Width, 50));
newImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedDocuments/") + fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

So how can we get image as I shown here with unique id and with half border on left side and bottom side?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this sample.

```
var img = DrawText("Tonton", "Unique Id(12345)");

private Image DrawText(String text, String subText)
    {
        var textColor = Color.Black;
        var backColor = Color.Transparent;

        var textFont = new Font("Arial", 15);
        Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

        var subTextFont = new Font("Arial", 7);
        Brush subTextBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

        //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
        Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
        Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
        SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, textFont);
        SizeF subTextSize = drawing.MeasureString(subText, subTextFont);

        //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
        img.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        //create a new image of the right size
        img = new Bitmap(((int)textSize.Width + (int)subTextSize.Width) - ((int)textSize.Width / 3), (int)textSize.Height + 15);

        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        drawing.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;

        //paint the background
        drawing.Clear(backColor);
        
        //Draw Text
        drawing.DrawString(text, textFont, textBrush, 5, 0);

        //Drawing Line
        var linePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        var height = (int)textSize.Height;
        var width = (int)textSize.Width;

        drawVerticalLine(drawing, linePen, 1, 0, height + 5);
        drawHorizontalLine(drawing, linePen, 0, height + 5, width / 3);

        //Darw Subtext
        drawing.DrawString(subText, subTextFont, subTextBrush, width / 3, height);

        drawing.Save();

        textBrush.Dispose();
        drawing.Dispose();

        return img;
    }

    private void drawHorizontalLine(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x, int y, int width)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x+width, y);
    }

    private void drawVerticalLine(Graphics graphics, Pen pen, int x, int y, int height)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x, y+height);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

I hope it helps. Happy coding.